# DragLeave fires when action is cancel, how to validate?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

Does anyone knows how can I validate if the event is raised because the DragAction changed to cancel, or because it actually object was dragged out from the control?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragleave.aspx

[edit]

In this part I start the drag in the object being dragged.

```
void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  var wasClicked = WasClicked;
  if (wasClicked != null)
  {
    WasClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
  // Select this UC on click.
  if (IsSelected == false)
    IsSelected = true;
  else
    IsSelected = false;

  if (IsSelected == true)
  {
    _beingDragged = true;
    DoDragDrop(this, DragDropEffects.Move);  
  }
  return;
}
```

This part the event validates when the object being dragged leaves the FlowLayoutPanel.

```
private void LocationControl_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (Control c in Controls)
  {
    if (((PersonDragDrop)c).beingDragged == true)
    {
      ((PersonDragDrop)c).LeaveLocation();
      DeletePerson((PersonDragDrop)c);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the value of `DragAction` also `Cancel` in the case of dragging out?

Comment: that is exactly the question, how I can check the value of DragAction inside the event? I have a custom FlowLayoutPanel with can accept drag objects, but if an object already in the panel is dragged but never left the panel, it fires that event, and cannot validate if it was because it left or because it was cancelled.

Comment: Can you share the event handler?

Comment: DragLeave is *not* intended to do anything like this.  It should only be used to restore D+D UI state, like restoring the cursor.  Only ever call something like "DeletePerson" in the DragDrop event handler.

Comment: Which technique do you suggest to control the objects that has being drag in and out, from one object to another?

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I used instead the function `private void PersonDragDrop_ParentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`